# Android Studio heap size

Tags: android, android-studio, size, heap-memory

i'm starting to develope applications with Android Studio but i have a problem with the heap size because it is full quickly and the program breaks. I've tried to increase this heap size in the options but the problem continues, can anyone help me please?

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18900271

Answer (score 0):

- If you have 4gb+ ram memory on your machine, increase `Xms` by 256MB and `Xmn` by 1650mb.
- In your `gradle.properties` put `org.gradle.daemon=true`
- settings > build, execution, deployment > build tools > gradle and CHECK `offline work`