# Android Studio - How to increase Allocated Heap Size

Tags: android, memory-management, crash, out-of-memory, android-studio

I've been using Android Studio for 3 months now and one of the apps I started on it has become fairly large.  The memory usage indicated at the bottom right of the program says my allocated heap is maxed at 494M.

[image]

When I start to change the XML files my memory usage quickly reaches that cap and the IDE crashes with an Out Of Memory error like this.

[image]

I've tried to increase the heap size using this but so far there has been no effect.

I've looked at dozens of articles and other questions on how to increase the heap size but none of their answers are working.  No matter what I do to the VMOPTIONS or the IDE settings the heap size never increases.  I believe I am editting the correct file for the VMOPTIONS because if I purposely give it an invalid command Android Studio complains about it and doesn't start.

I'm using windows 7 - 64 bit and have 16GB RAM.
Has anyone else had this problem with Android Studio? And were you able to fix it?

Comment: See @moxi's answer below for the most up-to-date information on configuring user-specific settings for memory and studio JVM startup http://stackoverflow.com/a/29057416/396005

Comment: Updated Android Studio documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I looked at my Environment Variables and had a System Variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m`, after changing this to `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` the max heap size increased accordingly.

Comment: There was no System Variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS. but i manually created new one and it works fine. thanx.

Comment: Good, this works! I'm wondering if to increase the heap size is a good thing... I mean, it works and surely in certain cases is the right way, but is it always the right way? Or may there be better solutions? Thanks!

Comment: is this problem also due to the heap size 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148374/how-to-solve-low-disk-space-for-android-studio

Comment: Didn't work for me either, but it turns out Android Studio had let some Java processes hanging from previous executions, and they were all obviously still using a lot of memory.

Comment: just comment out this line **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m**

Answer (score 163):

## -------EDIT--------

Android Studio 2.0 and above, you can create/edit this file by accessing "Edit Custom VM Options" from the Help menu.

## -------ORIGINAL ANSWER--------

Open file located at

```
/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions
```

Change the content to

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

`Xmx` specifies the maximum memory allocation pool for a Java Virtual Machine (JVM), while `Xms` specifies the initial memory allocation pool. Your JVM will be started with `Xms` amount of memory and will be able to use a maximum of `Xmx` amount of memory.

Save the `studio.vmoptions` file and restart Android Studio.

## Note:

If you changed the heap size for the IDE, you must restart Android Studio before the new memory settings are applied. ([source](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html))

Comment: This fixed a problem for me on a very large project where Android Studio would run out of memory after 15mn whilst building the symbol map. I changed Xms to 1024m and Xmx to 4096 and the symbol map was built in under 30 sec - so the garbage collector must have been thrashing for a long time.

Comment: As noted by Lord Flash: As of Android Studio 2.0, you can create/edit this file by accessing "Edit Custom VM Options" from the Help menu.

Comment: Thx, it's very usefull.
FYI, if you use the 64bits version, the file to edit is named studio64.exe.vmoptions.

Comment: @RikMaxSpeed, how much maximum have you obtained the heap size in your project. I am working on an app where I need around 1GB heap size for my static variables so the variables are available anytime but using largeHeap don't support that much storage size. It throws OutOfMemory around 600 MB which is the maximum memory android system provides my app at runtime

Comment: increasing xmx doesn't increase it! I still get the same error box

Answer (score 48):

Or, you can go to your `android-studio\bin` folder and change these -Xmx and -Xms values in `studio.exe.vmoptions` or `studio64.exe.vmoptions` files (depending on which version you are running).

Comment: This didn't work for me because the _JAVA_OPTIONS variable was being used as the default value.

Comment: Changed both options (vmoptions and _JAVA_OPTIONS) but I still have the error

Comment: If you purposely enter a syntax error into the vmoptions does it crash the program when you restart it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it should. Also, may I ask why would you enter a syntax error in vmoptions on purpose?

Comment: This works but now I get the firewall dialog every time I launch AS, I guess because touching an application file invalidated its signature - http://superuser.com/a/328802/79666

Comment: (The firewall dialog is only an issue on OS/X AFAIK.)

Comment: https://extremegtx.wordpress.com/2015/01/08/android-studio-speed-up-studio-and-gradle/

Comment: This is a bad idea becasue that might change. As stated here: https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/configuration use the Appropriate directory for a custom vmoptions.

Comment: This will take effect until you "invalidate and restart'

Answer (score 41):

> You should not edit any files in the IDE installation directory. Instead, you can customize the attributes by creating your own .properties or .vmoptions files in the following directories. (This has been possible on some platforms before, but it required you to copy and change the entire contents of the files. With the latest changes these properties are now additive instead such that you can set just the attributes you care about, and the rest will use the defaults from the IDE installation).

**Note: As of Android Studio 2.0, you can create/edit this file by accessing the "Edit Custom VM Options" file from the Help menu.**

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

[image]

Answer (score 37):

I increased my memory following the next Google documentation:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

By default Android Studio is assigned a max of 750Mb, I changed to 2048Mb.

I tried what google described but for me the only thing that it worked was to use an environment variable. I will describe what I did:

First I created a directory that I called .AndroidStudioSettings,

- `mkdir .AndroidStudioSettings`

Then I created a file called studio.vmoptions , and I put in that file the following content:

```
-Xms256m 
-Xmx2048m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Then I added the STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS environment variables in my .profile file:

- `export STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=/Users/youruser/.AndroidStudioSettings/studio.vmoptions`

Then I reload my .profile:

- `source ~/.profile`

And finally I open Android Studio:

- `open /Applications/Android\ Studio.app`

And now as you can see using the [status bar](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/status-bar.html?search=memory) , I have more than 2000 MB available for Android Studio:

[image]

You can customize your values according to your need in my case 2048Mb is enough.

UPDATE : Android Studio 2.0 let's you modify this file by accessing "Edit Custom VM Options" from the Help menu, just copy and paste the variables you might want to keep in order to increase it for everversion you might have on your box.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution work only when opening AS from shell?

Comment: Where are you typing the commands such as `export STUDIO_VM_OPTIONS=/Users/youruser/.AndroidStudioSettings/studio.vmoptions` in the terminal?

Answer (score 16):

You can try any one of the following

**1)Change the gradle.properties file and change the heap size as per your requirement.**

If **org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M** is not sufficient then change to **4096** as given

**org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M**
[image]

**2)"Edit Custom VM Options" from the Help menu.**

It will open studio.vmoptions / studio64.exe.vmoptions file.

[image]
Change the content to

-Xms128m

-Xmx4096m

-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m

-XX:+UseCompressedOops

Save the the file and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 15):

**Android Studio 3.1** has option to edit your customize virtual memory options.

You can go **Android Studio > Help > Edit Custom VM Options**

[image]

Then paste below settings code to **studio64.exe.vmoptions** file & Save it.

file location : "\Users\username\.AndroidStudio3.**\config\"

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: That last line is wrong -- Android Studio 3.2 crashes on startup with it there.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using **MAC BOOK**, this option is available inside **Applications** -> **Right click Android Studio** then choose **Show Package contents** -> **bin**.

[image]

or

open `-e /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions`

Then increase **`Xmx`** value

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Now your Android Studio will be super-fast.

Answer (score 11):

**Note:** *I now this is not the answer for the post, but maybe this will be helpful for some one that is looking.*

If Nothing of this works for you, try on a Mac this to see if helps you, in the last version of Android Studio, the studio.vmoptions is inside the AndroidStudio.app in your Applications folder.

So right click or ctrl click on your AndroidStudio.App and then select show package content the studio.vmoptions is in:

Contents/bin/studio.vmoptions

Replace or change it and you will get all the RAM you need.

[image]
[image]

Regards.

Comment: You should not change that file, but the one stated here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration. For Mac: ~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions

Answer (score 7):

I tried the _JAVA_OPTIONS thing but it wasn't working for me still.

In the end, what worked for me was the following:

- Launching studio64.exe instead of the studio.exe(I've got a 64-bits machine).
- Add/Change the following values in "studio64.exe.vmoptions":

```html
-Xms2048m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-Dfile.encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Did exactly the same as you, I still have the Out of Memory errors

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of Android Studio? I'm using Canary Channel and I've got 1.0 RC 4

Comment: No, I was on 0.8.14, but I found the cause of the memory leak. Creating a color named "light_gray" and using it in a layout file uses infinite memory... "light_grey" is ok though.

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of answers that are now outdated. The desired way of changing the heap size for Android Studio recently changed.

Users should now create their own vmoptions file in one of the following directories;

Windows:
`%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

Mac: 
`~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions`

Linux:
`~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions and/or ~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio64.vmoptions`

The contents of the newly created `*.vmoptions` file should be:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=96m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

To increase the RAM allotment change `-XmX750m` to another value.

Full instructions can be found here:
http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Comment: but there is no file `studio.vmoptions` at the path you mentioned. they are under `%AndroidStudioInstallationPath%\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions`

Comment: This is the right answer. Others are obsolete or discouraged.

Answer (score 6):

First check how much memory allocated for your android studio 
to check that follow this steps :

> File -> Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance

then check the show memory indicator option like below image red highlighted part
[image]

In my case my RAM is 12Gb so i have allocated memory for android studio 6gb .To edit that follow this steps

Help->Edit custom VM options

```
-Xmx6g
```

In my case, i have set it 6gb because my pc ram is 12 GB. Its upto you how much memory you want to allocate to your android studio

Answer (score 6):

This is how you change the heap size currently in Android Studio 3.6.1

On Windows in your Android Studio:

1. Select File -> Settings (the popup below will be displayed)

[image: Settings Dialog]

1. Select Appearance & Behavior
2. Select System Settings
3. Select Memory Settings

Then change the IDE Heap Size settings to your desired value

On Mac:

1. Select Android Studio
2. Select Preferences

The same pop up will appear. However, this time on the Mac its called Preferences.

Follow the same steps as the Windows version of Android Studio to adjust the heap size wants the Preferences dialog has been displayed

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OSX one can easily change heap size by going to first menu item, **Android Studio > preference > System Settings (left menu) > Memory Settings** and change heap size there in the dialog.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 7, the configuration files at `[INSTALL-LOCATION]\bin` seem to be ignored. Per the following Google documentation, the file to be modified should be here: `%USERPROFILE%\.AndroidStudio\studio[64].exe.vmoptions`

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

Odd that there is no such file upon a clean install of Android Studio 1.1 from the developer site. And they are in the old (ignored) location. Once I copy the file (`studio.exe.vmoptions` in my case) over and modify it, the change is respected.

However, the fun doesn't stop there. There's an upper value for `-Xmx` which may be related to the amount of memory in your system. I just bumped my machine's memory from 4Gb to 16Gb, and assumed I could set `-Xmx` to `2048m`, but I found that if I set it to anything larger than `1500m,` Android Studio would silently fail to launch with no indication at all as to why. I have more RAM on the way, so it will be interesting to see if I can increase the value at that point.

I hope this additional information is helpful. While all of the above replies were undoubtedly true at one point (and may still be in some environments), I found that this was the only approach that increased the memory used by AS for me.

Answer (score 2):

Had this `Xms` and `Xmx` memory low issue happen to me any time I was working with the XML. I also tried increasing this memory, only to find that it just took a little longer for it to happen again.

After getting very frustrated and almost deciding to convert all my current projects back over to Eclipse, which I did not want to do, I figured out what was causing it and was able to repeat this failure and prevent it every time.

While editing the XML in (Text view), and using the "Preview" render view, this causes the loss of memory, every time.  Turning off "Preview" and using the Design tab to render the screen only, I am able to use Android Studio all day long, with no crash.

I wish this could be fixed for good, because it would be very nice to use the "Preview" render while editing the XML, however I am glad I can keep using Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Open studio.vmoptions and change JVM options

studio.vmoptions locates at /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/bin/studio.vmoptions (Mac OS). In my machine, it looks like

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx800m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Change to

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

And restart Android Studio

See more [Android Studio website](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration)

Answer (score 2):

I found on on Windows 7/8 (64-bit), as of Android Studio 1.1.0:

`[INSTALL_DIR]\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions` be used (if it exists), otherwise it would always fall back to `%USERPROFILE%.\AndroidStudio\studio[64].exe.vmoptions`

If you want the settings managed from `%USERPROFILE%.\AndroidStudio\studio[64].exe.vmoptions`, just delete the one in the installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

Go in the Gradle Scripts -> local.properties and paste this

```
`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m`
```

, if you want to change it to 512. Hope it works !

Answer (score 2):

you are not supposed to modify the bin/studio.exe.vmoptions file, which will be verified during applying update patch.

Solutions are here http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration

copy that file into following location, then change the -Xmx1280m to whatever you want.

#### Windows:

`%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio.exe.vmoptions`
and/or
`%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\studio64.exe.vmoptions`

`%USERPROFILE%\.{FOLDER_NAME}\idea.properties`

#### Mac:

`~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions`
`~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/idea.properties`

#### Linux:

`~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio.vmoptions`
and/or
`~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/studio64.vmoptions`

`~/.{FOLDER_NAME}/idea.properties`

Comment: It is safer to use IntelliJs/Android Studios own function to do it: Open the IDE an click "Help" - > "Edit custom VM options"

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu, it's straight forward, clicking **Help > Edit Custom VM Options**
. The IDE asks whether to create for you a file, click OK.

An empty **studio64.vmoptions** file is create and paste the following variables:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Restart the IDE, the Max Heap Size is increased to: 4,062M

Answer (score 1):

May help someone that get this problem:

I edit `studio64.exe.vmoptions` file, but failed to save.

So I opened this file with Notepad++ in `Run as Administrator` mode and then saved successfully.

Answer (score 1):

IF by changing or creating the `.studio.exe.vmoptions` doesn't work, then try changing the `gradle.properties` file and change the heap size as per your requirement.

It really worked for me on my Windows 7 with 4Gb RAM and Android Studio 2.2 install on it.

Working properly with no error and displaying 'Gradle Sync complete'

Comment: I had to add a grade.properties  in order to  set max heap size that was used when I debug my app.  But I have to ask, why doesn't  setting the studio.vmoptions as mentioned in the Android Studio configuration page not work as advertised?  My concern is that I am doing something fundamentally wrong (but it sure doesn't look like it).  (Thanks)   I  posted a detailed question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40833031/maximum-heap-size-not-being-set-as-indicated-in-studio-vmoptions-file

Answer (score 0):

```html
-Xms256m 
-Xmx2048m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m 
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: A little explanation would surely improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022, you may check this link here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

**Windows**

Syntax: `%APPDATA%\Google\<product><version>`

Example: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1`

**macOS**

Syntax: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/<product><version>`

Example: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1`

Answer (score 0):

1. File
2. Settings
3. Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> memory size
4. IDE max heap size : choose the correct value from the combo
5. Apply -> yes
6. OK

have a good job.