# Aspose.Cells in Android Studio : OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android-studio, aspose-cells

I have referenced Aspose.Cells jar file in my Android Studio project, but I get the following error when I compile:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':kpi:preDexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\jcmag_000\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --output D:\Android\MockupBuilder\kpi\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\aspose-cells-8.1.0-ee32824075207ab5167ea34e50ad48740612abbf.jar D:\Android\MockupBuilder\kpi\libs\aspose-cells-8.1.0.jar
>   Error Code:
>       3
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>           at com.android.dx.util.IntList.growIfNeeded(IntList.java:274)
>           at com.android.dx.util.IntList.add(IntList.java:217)
>           at com.android.dx.util.LabeledList.addLabelIndex(LabeledList.java:96)
>           at com.android.dx.util.LabeledList.set(LabeledList.java:184)
>           at com.android.dx.rop.code.BasicBlockList.set(BasicBlockList.java:77)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertBasicBlocks(SsaToRop.java:259)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convert(SsaToRop.java:123)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.back.SsaToRop.convertToRopMethod(SsaToRop.java:69)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimizeMinimizeRegisters(Optimizer.java:146)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:106)
>           at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:299)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:139)
>           at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:94)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:682)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
>           at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Cells for Android has been successfully tested with [ADT Bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) as Android Studio is not fully stable yet.

If you are experiencing `OutOfMemoryError` on Android Studio try increasing the allocated memory. Check answers on [Android Studio - How to increase Allocated Heap Size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18723755).

PS: I am a developer at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

```
dexOptions {
   incremental true

   //javaMaxHeapSize=1024M for 32bit Java,2048M for 64bit Java

   javaMaxHeapSize "1024M"

   //javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}
```