# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:java.lang.outofmemoryexception:java heap space

Tags: android

i was compiling an android app with gradle in my android studio 1.0.2 version and i got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
    /home/sujata/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk/build-tools/build-tools-21.1.1/dx --dex --no-optimize --multi-dex --main-dex-list 
  Error Code:
    3
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.OneLocalsArray.copy(OneLocalsArray.java:50)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.OneLocalsArray.copy(OneLocalsArray.java:32)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Frame.copy(Frame.java:98)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.processBlock(Ropper.java:786)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.doit(Ropper.java:742)
        at com.android.dx.cf.code.Ropper.convert(Ropper.java:349)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:280)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
        at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:82)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
        at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:332)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:243)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: This error is due to multiple copies of same library referenced from your project. Check and remove one copy out of it.

Comment: i have used 2 libraries in the same project https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM and https://github.com/TonicArtos/StickyGridHeaders . This is why i am getting above error. But i want both the libraries to be added in my project. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Comment: i referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367071/android-studio-1-0-failing-build-at-dexdebug-or-dexrelease this link to solve my issue of building and running the app