# Java Heap Space error while running Android app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a newbie to `Android Studio`. When I try to run a sample Android app I am getting the following error :

`Error:Java heap space
Please assign more memory to Gradle in the project's gradle.properties file.`

I have changed the following in the `studio.vmoptions` file in `bin`

-Xms512m

-Xmx1024m

But changing to the above values also doesn't help.

Can anyone guide me step by step what to do.

Comment: Might be a duplicate of:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size

Answer (score 0):

There is possibly an infinite loop in your code using up all the virtual memory, try checking any loops or recursive function calls. Or you can post your code or part of it to help you out better