# How to Solve Low Disk Space for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error randomly and not sure as to why my disk space is getting low for Android Studio..

> Low disk space on a Android Studio system directory partition

**Update**

This Application is installed on a mac running 10.10.1 w/ 251GB internal storage and an OS restore Drive taking 10GB.

I think the problem is, once the application was installed it was placed on the smaller partition.

I will attempt to remove this application and all files associated to it, and reinstall. Hopefully this will solve the issue.

Comment: how do I choose the partition, the studio installer doesn't give any options

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory in idea.properties or the studio.vmoptions??

Comment: @JoseGonzalez this was not a problem with android studio not having enough memory, but more of the partition it was on was restricting it from allocating more space.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can install studio and SDK separately into different partitions: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other

Or you can move your existing SDK folder anywhere and then just point studio to it in preferences.

Also consider that AVD files are actually stored in your system **user** folder (`user/.android/avd` on Windows, not sure where exactly on mac), not in SDK folder.

Comment: this is the most helpful answer I have found. My problem was that it initially installed on the smaller partition. I then needed to uninstall the application from that partition and re-install on the larger partition. After that it worked great.

Answer (score 8):

I was getting this error and restarting Android Studio and adding more memory did not help. At this point I noticed it was happening across all my emulators in android studio. It turns out that some of the files in the emulators could not be read because they have became corrupt. The simplest solution is usually the best answer so restarting my computer fixed it. Hope this saves someone time!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, I installed android studio a 128gb partition and togther with JAVA jdk and all sdk related file it consume most of its disk space. I re-install it on a larger partition and it solve my problem.

Comment: also make sure to also save AppData\Local\Android\sdk on the larger partition

Comment: how do I choose the partition, the sdk installer doesn't provide any options

Answer (score 7):

Android Studio with SDK Tools,JDK and AVD takes almost 30gb but I believe that it needs a little bit more to work properly.Everything bigger than 40gb it's Ok.It depends on the number of SDK's that you download.If you have 40gb of free disk space you will never have this message.Sometimes crashes or pop messages if you use it a lot of days without reboot your computer make a reboot and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 5):

I just compressed the drive and there was 25GB of space available now. The problem vanished. Then when i shutted down my PC and restarted it the next day I got an error BOOTMGR compressed. SO i followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tnyhz-CRQU and fixed it and now I still have 25GB space available. It worked for me

Answer (score 5):

Please open below mention path and delete you all avd's here.

**C:\Users{Username}.android\avd**

Sometimes, deleting emulator in android studio is not enough to reduce all the spaces grab by these emulator's. **So deleting these emulator's from above mention path**.

Answer (score 3):

You can click on your SDK manager then navigate to **Appearance settings > systems settings > Android SDK.** From here just click on **optimize disk space** on the top right corner of your window. I was able to clear about 15gb then it worked smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem and I solved by deleting some unwanted files from my disk.

Reason - The disk space is low which u have android SDK and android studio file.

solution - Delect some files from your disk which has your android sdk and studio.

Comment: I have a slightly different problem. The SDK module thinks that I have 0 bytes of storage, but I have 851 GB free space on my system. The SDK Tools module gives me this message. I have rebooted a number of times without changing anything. Sorry if I put this in the wrong place!

Answer (score 0):

If you have facing the issue in low disk space in android studio,just delete the unwanted emulator in your AVD manager.I wasted the whole to try other things.it help full to any one.it working for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked only after restarting my MacBook ‍♂️