# BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray OutOfMemory

Tags: java, android, bitmap

i'm trying to get a Jpeg from `Camera.PictureCallback onPictureTaken` but when i do this

`bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);`

The first time this is what appears on logcat:

Grow heap (frag case) to 48.886MB for 15728656-byte allocation

And when I try to retake a picture the app crashes with this stack trace:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:603)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:626)
            at com.delsorboilario.brianzashop.Scatta$5.onPictureTaken(Scatta.java:216)
            at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:987)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the code:

```
android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, android.hardware.Camera camera) {

         bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);


        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmapImage);

        File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

        System.out.println("aaaaaa "+finalFile);


    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Following MicheleLacorte's suggest, i'm try to recycle Bitmap after take `File finalFile`

and its ok but when I try to display image from that path i've the same error.

Comment: Are you using Android Studio ?

Comment: I also had similar problems I suggest you read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size , and try to " destroy " the bitmap once you no longer need with Bitmap.recycle ( ); or bitmap = null; (bad choice)

Answer (score 3):

Loading large bitmaps is really tough in Android
look at this

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: thanks for your suggest, can you give me a concrete example on my case? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Following this http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html   , I just changed the decodeSampledBitmapFromResource static method to cater for decodeByteArray instead of decodeResource. I put the methods in my util class.

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}    

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(byte[] data, int   reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //options.inPurgeable = true; 
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
}
```

Then try this with your code:

```
android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new  android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback() {
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, android.hardware.Camera camera) {

     //bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
     // Utils is my utility class
     bitmapImage = Utils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 50,50);


    Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), bitmapImage);

    File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

    System.out.println("aaaaaa "+finalFile);


}
```

};

Answer (score 2):

You say it's when you take a second picture you have problems? Before you allow the user to retake the picture, you need to do something with the first picture to clear up some memory. If you don't intend to continue displaying it, save it to a cache file on disk, and then release your memory resources with

```
bitmapImage.recycle();
bitmapImage = null;
```

If you do need to keep it displayed on screen, then downsample it as much as you can without making it look terrible and make sure you're not holding a reference to the original full-size image. Also see if you can do some compression on the image as you get it from the byte array.