# How much memory should I be using for an image in Android Studio?

Tags: android, memory-management

My application uses far too much memory, and uses a lot of images on one of the activities. I went to my main menu which only has 2 image buttons and a background image and removed all of the images from it to see what kind of memory it used... It still seems pretty high for nothing on the page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eubl.jpg

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or are these normal numbers? In the activity that uses a lot of images, the allocated memory is much higher around 250MB, and crashes if I don't use my tiny scaled down images.

Comment: Use Glide to Load your images

Comment: It's better than Picasso?
Do you know why my memory allocation is so high with blank image buttons and blank background?

Comment: Yes, its better than picasso. you may be implementing it in a wrong way. maybe you should post your code.

Comment: I made a fresh blank application, and put 2 image buttons into it. There is no code and its 23MB allocated. Is this normal?

Comment: Am not quite sure whether its normal or not. I have an App which loads lots of images from the web and its allocated 10mb+ , you might want to take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size

Comment: Thanks, using glide on 43 of my images reduced the memory allocated from 220MB to 189MB. I don't think it's fully the problem but it definitely helps to load them from the internet.