# Gradle memory allocation

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

When starting a new project gradle sync fails, and the only solution That fix it is adding to gradle.properties file in the project the next line:
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

I know it allocates more memory than specified in the begining, my question is if there is a way of fixing it without making changes in the gradle file?Or where can I change it to permanently allocate 1024 without me adding it every time to the gradle file?
TNX

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the JVM args with that flag. To make more "permanent" modifications to your memory allocation, you should check Environment Variables. You should have a System Variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value `-Xms256m` `-Xmx512m`. You can change it here, maybe to `-Xms256m` `-Xmx1024m` to increase the JVM max heap size accordingly.

Also see the answers here: [Android Studio - How to increase Allocated Heap Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size)