# Android Studio refuses to change its memory

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the memory allocated to Android Studio to 750mb but it's not working.

To change it I clicked on **Help > Edit Custom VM Options...**. It prompted me to create the new file which I did. I then entered `-Xmx750m` and restarted Android Studio but I am stilll seeing this:

[image: screensho]

Android Studio info:

```
Android Studio 2.2.3
Build #AI-145.3537739, built on December 2, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_111-b14 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Anothing thing: though I have updated to version 2.2.3 as can be seen above, Android Studio is still using folder `.AndroidStudio2.1`.

The machine I am using is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Have you tried it https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html ?

Comment: @rogerwar yes I tried it.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size?

Answer (score 0):

This command will search for all copies of the options files and show the current Xmx setting for each one (assuming there is at least 2 on your system).

```
find / -name "studio*.vmoptions" 2>/dev/null | xargs -L 10 grep 'Xmx'
```

It will be faster if you know that these settings are all in your home directory, to change the "/" into "/home/myhome/" or whatever it is.

This should tell you if what is going on is that the menu commands are editing one file and the startup command is reading a different one, as I suspect.