# How to increase the cache size in Glide android?

Tags: android, caching, android-glide, image-caching

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#size) ,

> The internal cache factory places the disk cache in your application's internal cache directory and sets a maximum size of 250MB.

As I am trying to implement some offline features in my apps, it possibly require cache size larger than 250MB. So does Glide allow to modify the cache size or I need to find out an alternative way of doing this? If so, what mechanism should I follow?

I have seen in the [documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#size) an approach to increase that.

```
builder.setDiskCache(
new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, yourSizeInBytes));
```

How do I implement that in my code?

Comment: It is literally the next line of the documentation.

Comment: Yes, but how? and where to implement that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738237/3364266 Check this link

Comment: I am not forced you but please try to increase your heap size by using this code inside gradle.  javaMaxHeapSize "16g"

Answer (score 10):

See [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Configuration#size).

> You can set the size of the disk cache using the InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory.

```
builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, yourSizeInBytes));
```

You can apply in this your project like below:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StatFs;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.cache.InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule;
import com.example.MyApplication;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LimitCacheSizeGlideModule implements GlideModule {

    @Override
    public void applyOptions(Context context, GlideBuilder builder) {
        if (MyApplication.from(context).isTest()) 
            return; // NOTE: StatFs will crash on robolectric.
        builder.setDiskCache(new InternalCacheDiskCacheFactory(context, yourSizeInBytes));

    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide) {
    }


}
```

and then in your manifest add it like this

```
<manifest

    ...

    <application>

        <meta-data
            android:name="YourPackageNameHere.LimitCacheSizeGlideModule"
            android:value="GlideModule" />

        ...

    </application>
</manifest>
```