# How increase heap size in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, memory

I have a problem that on my PC android studio are laging. It's not the newest a notebok but I have 8gb RAM. I try to increase memory to android studio by editing files: android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions and android-studio\bin\studio64.exe.vmoptions but it dosen't help me (allocate heap size dosen't change - it's 445M).

My example studio64.exe.vmoptions is:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-XX:MaxJavaStackTraceDepth=-1
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
```

Do you know whhy heap size dosen't change (of course after restart android studio)

Comment: Check the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723755/android-studio-how-to-increase-allocated-heap-size)

Answer (score 0):

> allocate heap size doesn't change - it's 445M

because your windows handle it

reading [the source](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)

If you are working (1) on a large project, or

(2) your system has _!_a_lot_of_RAM_!_,

***you can improve*** performance ***by increasing the maximum*** heap size

is it your case?..

or maybe you need *to do some alternative*:

described in "***[Configure the IDE for low-memory machines](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html)***" menu point (my choice by the way) at the same source?

whish you all of good in any case!